# Why does initializing class variables using std::numeric_limits take so long?

Tags: c++, performance, initialization, numeric-limits

I have a C++ class which gets instantiated a very large number of times. It has an `unsigned short` private member. I am getting very different runtime performance depending on whether I initialize it with a hard-coded value `65535` vs when I initialize it with `std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max()`, even though they are ostensibly the same value.

I am trying to understand why there is such a large performance difference, as I would have thought these would be equivalent after compilation. Is it just bad practice to initialize using `std::numeric_limits`?

Minimal working example below (I've included no initialization for reference):

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

#define TYPE unsigned short
const TYPE max = 65535; // value returned by std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max();

class numeric_test_no_init
{
    public:
        numeric_test_no_init() noexcept
        {
            return;
        }
    private:
        TYPE _l;
};

class numeric_test_zero_init
{
    public:
        numeric_test_zero_init() noexcept
        {
            _l=max;
        }
    private:
        TYPE _l;
};

class numeric_test_max_init
{
    public:
        numeric_test_max_init() noexcept
        {
            _l=std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::max();
        }
    private:
        TYPE _l;
};

int main() {
    
    size_t inner_size = 10000000;
    size_t outer_size = 1000;
    clock_t begin, end;
    double elapsed_secs;

    begin = clock();
    for (size_t i=0;i<outer_size;++i)
        std::vector<numeric_test_no_init> no_init(inner_size);
    end = clock();
    elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "numeric_test_no_init took " << elapsed_secs << " seconds." << std::endl;
    
    begin = clock();
    for (size_t i=0;i<outer_size;++i)
        std::vector<numeric_test_zero_init> zero_init(inner_size);
    end = clock();
    elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "numeric_test_zero_init took " << elapsed_secs << " seconds." << std::endl;

    begin = clock();
    for (size_t i=0;i<outer_size;++i)
        std::vector<numeric_test_max_init> max_init(inner_size);
    end = clock();
    elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "numeric_test_max_init took " << elapsed_secs << " seconds." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
numeric_test_no_init took 0.003331 seconds.
numeric_test_zero_init took 2.12012 seconds.
numeric_test_max_init took 16.6588 seconds.
```

I am compiling using GCC 11.4.0 (default for Ubuntu 22.04) with optimization enabled `-03`.

Update: the performance discrepancy goes away when I upgrade GCC to 13.2. Thank you @retired-ninja for the link demonstrating that.

Comment: Because you did not compile with optimizations enabled?

Comment: edited to clarify optimization is enabled

Comment: How did you compile your code? Debug build or release build (aka without or with optimizations enabled)? It matters *a lot*. Unoptimized debug builds are notoriously slow. To get proper performance, you *need* to enable the compilers optimizer (which is usually *not* the default).

Comment: Side note; enabling Link Time Optimization (aka `lto`) can also often improve performance.

Comment: What compiler, compiler version, and compiler command line are you using? With no optimizations on the command line it times out here, but with `-O3` it does not and the results are nearly identical. https://godbolt.org/z/88WGjsrP3

Comment: *"take so long"* repeating anything 10_000_000_000 times gonna be slow. For example, if it take only 1 instruction of 1 cycle on a 4.7GHz CPU, this will take 2.12 seconds (so I assume the second use-case takes less than 2 cycles). Based on this reasoning, the last use-case should take about 8 cycles/item at this frequency. My guess is that the last is just not fully inlined. Just calling the constructor of the items is actually expensive at this scale. The first use-case certainly measures nothing already.

Comment: edited with compiler and version

Comment: It should be noted that nowhere in your code do you actually initialize `_1`.  All of your constructors default initialize `_1` since their member initializer list is empty.  They all *assign* to `_1` in the body of the constructor.  All of your constructors should be on the form of `type_name() : _1( /*some value if you do not want 0 here*/) {}`

Comment: Also note, `return;` inside a constructor is a non-op.  Constructors don't return values so it's meaning to return a value.  A do nothing default constructor has the form `type_name() {}`

Comment: I can somewhat reproduce this issue on compiler explorer [here](https://godbolt.org/z/exjxnGzE8).  My guess is a bad implementation of the function.

Comment: @NathanOliver That may be something, given that `std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max` returns `USHRT_MAX` and the macro is required to be `int` or `unsigned int` type. There is a difference in assembly, but I don't quite understand it. Although I don't understand why compiler didn't remove all the initialisations altogether.

Comment: A more realistic benchmark shows no difference: https://quick-bench.com/q/DwxZ_oTDXYhkLWBxcGe1HX1ej6E and the assembly is identical https://quick-bench.com/q/HPMxA7-BMgx03jmuKtXdOUnto1w

Comment: @Peter No, the expression from macro expansion must undergo integer promotions (at least since C17, didn't check earlier). See https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf 5.2.4.2.1 #1. C++ standard has a note about that too: http://eel.is/c++draft/climits.syn#note-1. But it's true that `std::numeric_limits::max()` is only required to be equivalent to macro, so that leaves room for quality of implementation issues.